# Left $k[x]$-module $V$ induced by a linear transformation $T$, how to find the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

$V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space, $k$ is a field(may not be algebraically closed)

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be  a linear transformation over $k$, then $T$ induces a left $k[x]$-module $V$ by define

$f*v=f(T)(v)$  for any $f\in k[x],v\in V$.

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, by elementary divisors theorem we have the following isomorphism of left
$k[X]$-modules:

$V\cong k[x]/(f_1)\oplus k[x]/(f_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus k[x]/(f_s)$

where $f_i$  are nonzero monic polynomials in $k[X]$ for which $f_1|f_2|\cdots |f_s$.

The question is :

how to prove that $f_s$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ and $\prod f_i$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

One easily sees that for direct sums of submodules ($T$-stable subspaces), the minimal polynomial of the sum is the least common multiple of the minimal polynomial of the summands, while the characteristic polynomial of the sum is the product of the characteristic polynomials of the summands. The result now follows from the fact that $k[x]/f$ for any monic polynomial $f$ has $f$ both as minimum and as characteristic polynomial.

That $f$ is the minimal polynomial of (the action of multiplication by $x$ on) $k[x]/f$ is immediate from the definition. That $f$ is also the characteristic polynomial follows either from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (since $\dim_k(k[x]/f)=\deg(f)$) or from the fact that the characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix of$~f$ is $f$ (shown for instance by induction on $\deg(f)$), since the matrix of multiplication by $x$ on $k[x]/f$, with respect to the most obvious basis, is the companion matrix of$~f$.